# JS packer + minifier + reduce

Tags: javascript

Is there any analyser/parser that will parse my code, take the code from libraries that i really use and need, reduce unnecessary library code and make finally a minified package?

For example if im using only `$(smth).show()` in `jQuery` then this reducer only take the code and dependencies responsible for `show()` and exactly this case of the selector and remove anything else

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very popular tool for this is [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which in its newest release v4 has "[tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx)" capabilities. It can remove unnecessary code. (and optionally minifies and reduces, creates sourcemaps and more).
Another such bundler is [RollupJS](https://rollupjs.org/).

However

- your code (and the code in the libraries you are using) has to be written in a very specific way in order for treeshaking to work.
- webpack and rollup.js can take some time to learn and set-up
- they are nodejs based so you need to learn node concepts first

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks

Comment: i've also found `google closure compiler` with `advanced mode` which is the best for JS optimizing as far as i can see